# Getting error as "name 'result' is not defined"

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I'm running this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from fbprophet import Prophet
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\XXX.csv')
ids = data['id'].unique()
series = []
for id in ids:
   f = data[data['id'] == id]
   frames.append(f)

def run_prophet(timeserie):
    model = Prophet(yearly_seasonality=False,daily_seasonality=False)
    model.fit(timeserie)
    forecast = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=90, include_history=False)
    forecast = model.predict(forecast)
    return forecast

results = list(map(lambda timeserie: run_prophet(timeserie), series))

result[0] 
result[1]
```

But after result[0] I get the error "name 'result' is not defined". What can I do? Thanks

The structure of the data is:

```
id        ds        y
id_1  2017-01-01    11
id_2  2017-01-01    13
```

Comment: You never defined/set a variable "result". The error is not surprising.

Answer (score 0):

the variable should be named 'results' not 'result'. Also I should point out that pandas has an apply method https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html

Comment: Thanks. Changed it and now I get the error "List index out of range". Do you know what can I do?

Comment: Looks like you map a lambda function to your series list, but the code you provided shows that the series list is empty so there’s nothing to index. Perhaps instead of frames.append(f) you mean series.append(f)?

Answer (score 0):

Let replace your 2 last line by:

```
results[0] 
results[1]
```

Comment: Thanks. Changed it and now I get the error "List index out of range". Do you know what can I do?